# Build native OpenSSL library for WP8 Platform

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, openssl

I am creating Windows phone 8 application.I need to create App which uses compiled `OpenSSL` library.I was following [standard](http://www.openssl.org/source/) latest library.

I am following `INSTALL.W64` steps, as I don't know which INSTALL.* to be used.As my machine is 64 bit I preferred this:

To build for Win64/x64:

1 perl Configure VC-WIN64A
 2 ms\do_win64a
 3 nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
 4 cd out32dll
 5 ..\ms\test

Using Visual Studio Command Prompt.Upto step 2 is fine.At 3rd step it fails to build and doesn't create library in out32dll Folder.It gives error like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\include\windows.h(182) : fatal err
or C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winreg.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
\VC\WPSDK\WP80\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

My question is :**Is really OpenSSL supported for Windows Phone Platform**.As I seen [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4085f910-95dc-4862-9cc4-935c04d656f1/openssl-on-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop) which is true/false I am not sure.

Apart from this standard way I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203985/how-to-build-openssl-for-wp8) solution.Able to complete steps mentioned in answer.got build compiled in visual studio.Referenced `OpenSSLWP8` in Windows Phone 8 Project.Compiled `libeay32`.

But when I try to create reference `NativeCrypto nc = new NativeCrypto()` I get `FileNotFoundException` in that library.Am I missing something?

Which solution is better or there is any other solution available so that I can build `OpenSSL` for **WP8**.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Where did you read that OpenSSL supported Windows Phone 8?

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/MartinMReed/OpenSSL-WP8).They build a sample WinRT component having get,accept methods for WP8.

Comment: We need to see a `diff` of their changes to see if they are OK. I know they could not fix some things.

Comment: With Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, Microsoft has enabled WinSock and OpenSSL for Windows Phone and Windows Store apps. You can use WinSock APIs and hence many popular OSS libraries such as libcURL, libwebsockets, OpenSSL etc.
More about it here - http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/13/winsock-and-more-open-source-for-your-windows-store-apps/

Comment: Building OpenSSL on Windows Phone/ Windows RT is addresed [on this answer][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26415455/1936521

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: Is really OpenSSL supported for Windows Phone Platform. As I seen this which is true/false I am not sure.

Not officially.

I know one of the OpenSSL developers regularly build OpenSSL for Windows 8. I was also able to build for Windows 8. However...

I've got a bunch of patches for Windows RT and Windows Phone. The patches add three new targets, and it don't use `VC-WIN64A`. The added targets are `VC-WP8-X86`, `VC-WP8-ARM`, and `VC-WINRT-ARM`.

I added two new defines (`OPENSSL_SYS_WINRT` and `OPENSSL_SYS_WINPHONE`) so a lot of this went on:

```
-#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
+#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__) && !defined(OPENSSL_SYS_WINCE) &&
     !defined(OPENSSL_SYS_WINRT) && !defined(OPENSSL_SYS_WINPHONE)
```

The cflags needed some tuning. For example, here's from Windows RT:

```
+    $base_cflags.= " /D WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_PARTITION_APP";
+    $base_cflags.= " /FI SDKDDKVer.h /FI winapifamily.h";
```

And Windows Phone:

```
+    $base_cflags.= " /D WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP";
+    $base_cflags.= " /AI\"$ENV{'WINDOWSMETADATA'}\"";
+    $base_cflags.= " /FI SDKDDKVer.h /FI winapifamily.h";
```

The Windows RT target is severely crippled. As an example of how bad things are on Windows RT: the target needed both `-DOPENSSL_NO_SOCK` and `-DOPENSSL_NO_DGRAM` because applications are not allowed to access the `socket` API. That makes it pretty useless SSL library since TCP and UDP was gutted.

The Windows Phone target is a little better. Windows Phone allows access to the `socket` API (so TCP and UDP are available), but the random number generator seeding is broken. Its broken because Microsoft does not provide `CryptGenRandom` or the older Win32 screen APIs that were used to scrape state. Application will need to explicitly seed from `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

You can see traces of my suffering on Stack Overflow. For example, [Windows RT: where is sockaddr_in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120275/windows-rt-where-is-sockaddr-in).

Comment: Thanks for answer,It will be helpful if you direct me to steps of building OpenSSL library for WP8 if possible.any hopes!!!

Comment: you know OpenSSL very well,so you can better give me right direction to build OpenSSL for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @vits - I can't share them because they are not public. Try the MartinReed Github. It looks like he has a Visual Studio project.

Comment: @vits - Here's a similar port for Crypto++. First, the diff: [Crypto++, WP8/ARM cross-compile patch](http://pastebin.com/xz86h2WG); and second, the [Crypto++, WP8/ARM cross-compile batch file](http://pastebin.com/Ku9BtMfD) to build the library after patching. It should give you an idea of how to do things for WP8/ARM. You can use similar for OpenSSL. The OpenSSL build system on Windows sucks and its too complicated.

Comment: yes, As I mentioned above,that I used MartinReed Github as a 2nd approach...able to build that..but there are some problem that I mentioned above...Also,I checked Crypto++,it will give me option for encryption/decryption but what about Secure Channel?